# Problem in sending JsonString to Python endpoint using Netsuite script

Tags: javascript, flask, netsuite, suitescript, erp

I have a simple python route as follows:-

`@app.route('/api/customer/', methods=['PUT'])
def check():
  data=request.json
  return data`

I'm trying to call this python route using suite script in Oracle Netsuite. Here is the code for Requesting part of my suitescript.

```
nlapiRequestUrl(url,data,headers,'PUT')

var jsonVar = [{"email":"john@email.com","lastname":"Famous","firstname":"John"}];
var data = JSON.stringify(jsonVar);
```

When I am executing my suite script, I am Getting the following error in the netsuite app. [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apoXB.png)

It would be a great help if some one can give me a head's up.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is that code accurate? It shows setting `data` after you make the request.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```py
   @app.route('/api/customer/', methods=['PUT'])
    def check():
        """
        return the data in the request
        """
        return json_result(request.json)
```